# Sequential calculations fail in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence, calculation

I tried to do some calculations with a constant and several variables in a dataframe.

For example we can use the following dummy data

```
constant <- 100
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),
            c(4,3,6,1,4),
            c(2,5,6,6,2),
            c(5,5,5,1,2),
            c(3,6,4,3,1)))
colnames(df) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")
```

Now say that for every row in my dataframe I want to multiply my constant with variable bb, then cc, and then dd sequentially. I tried

```
answers <- sapply(df, function(x) constant * (1 + x[,2:4])
```

and similar attempts with lapply.

How would I go about it so that I get my: constant * bb * cc * dd? They are percentages, that is why I have the (1+... there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with `apply()`:

```
#Data
constant <- 100
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5),
                          c(4,3,6,1,4),
                          c(2,5,6,6,2),
                          c(5,5,5,1,2),
                          c(3,6,4,3,1)))
colnames(df) <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")
#Apply
answers <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df,1, function(x) constant * (1 + x))))
```

Output:

```
answers
   aa  bb  cc  dd  ee
1 200 500 300 600 400
2 300 400 600 600 700
3 400 700 700 600 500
4 500 200 700 200 400
5 600 500 300 300 200
```

Or using `dplyr` with `across()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
answer <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~constant * (1 + .)))
```

Output:

```
   aa  bb  cc  dd  ee
1 200 500 300 600 400
2 300 400 600 600 700
3 400 700 700 600 500
4 500 200 700 200 400
5 600 500 300 300 200
```

Or with the same `sapply()`:

```
#Code 3
answers <- sapply(df,function(x) constant * (1 + x))
answers <- as.data.frame(answers)
```

Output:

```
   aa  bb  cc  dd  ee
1 200 500 300 600 400
2 300 400 600 600 700
3 400 700 700 600 500
4 500 200 700 200 400
5 600 500 300 300 200
```

Or any of these options will produce same output:

```
#Code 4
answers <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(df,function(x) constant * (1 + x))))
#Code 5
answers <- as.data.frame(mapply(function(x) constant * (1 + x),x=df))
```